# Can i use Turtlebot Without Laptop by using Android phone/uc board

Tags: raspberrypi, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm new to this turtlebot.
I was wondered to see a laptop for turtlebot, why can't we use some embedded board like **friendly arm board**

```
                   http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440
```

or **raspberry pi** instead of laptop,
and one more thing is that can we use ***android phone*** directly connected instead of laptop.
if anyone already done it, can you give me a link to know it.
Thanks in Advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57359/can-i-use-turtlebot-without-laptop-by-using-android-phone/uc-board/) by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, No.

ROS is targeted towards linux platforms, and binary packages are provided for Ubuntu x86/x86_64. The further you get from that platform, the more trouble you'll have getting things to run.

All but the fastest ARM boards lack the CPU power to run the OpenNI (Kinect) driver well, and getting the OpenNI and pointcloud tools to compile on ARM is not easy, and takes a long time. The raspberry pi is the least powerful ARM that I would even attempt to use on a turtlebot, and I wouldn't really expect it to work very well.

Running ROS on Ubuntu on a phone is possible, but in addition to the issues with ARM you'll also have to deal with limited USB bandwidth and special cables to connect USB devices to the phone.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2